# Scan without spaces in R?

Tags: r

How do I scan for individual chars in a .txt for R? From my understanding, scan uses whitespace as separators, but if i want to use white space as something to scan for in R how do i do this?

ie (I want to scan the string "Hello World") how do i get H,e,l,l,o, ,W,o,r,l,d ?

Comment: Does `readLines` do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

`strsplit` would also be your friend here:

```
test <- readLines(textConnection("Hello world
Line two"))
strsplit(test,"")


> strsplit(test,"")
[[1]]
 [1] "H" "e" "l" "l" "o" " " "w" "o" "r" "l" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "L" "i" "n" "e" " " "t" "w" "o"
```

And unlisted as suggested by @Thilo...

```
> unlist(strsplit(test,""))
 [1] "H" "e" "l" "l" "o" " " "w" "o" "r" "l" "d" "L" "i" "n" "e" " " "t" "w" "o"
```

Comment: +1 for `strsplit` with empty argument. Didn't think of this one.

Comment: Of course strsplit is very useful for this purpose, but what about if you want to read just n first elements of a file, is there any R function? If you are iteratively reading large files you could be interested in reading not just i first lines but n first elements regardless the number of line.

Comment: @TomásNavarro - `readChar("filename.txt", nchars=10)` can handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would go a two-step approach: First read the file as plain text with `readLines` and then split the single lines to vectors of characters:

```
lines <- readLines("test.txt")
characterlist <- lapply(a, function(x) substring(x, 1:nchar(x), 1:nchar(x)))
```

Note that this approach does not return a well formed matrix or data.frame, but a list.

Depending on what you want to do, there might be a few different modifications:

```
unlist(characterlist)
```

gives you a vector of all characters in a row. If your textfile is so well behaved that you have exactly the same number of characters in each line, you may just add `simplify=T` to `lapply` and hopfully will get a matrix of your characters.

Comment: Thank you! This is heading in the right direction, i just have to do more formatting to the charlist but this is essentially what i want

Comment: If the answers solved your problem, you can mark one answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark. This way others do not have to try to help anymore. (I would prefere @thelatemail's answer, it is certainly the better approach)